# How to share files created by an app?

Tags: windows-phone-7, service, communication, file-sharing

How do I share files (music, video, image) create by my app? I am interested in sharing audio file specifically.

Imagine I have a program that generates wav file.
How do I take it from isolated storage?

Is it possible to sent an attachment with e-mail?
Save it on SkyDrive?
Share on Facebook?
Put it to media library?

At least in some convenient for a user way to take it out from WP7 device?

Any help regarding this topic would be welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly send it as an attachment through the EmailComposerTask, however you can use your own implementation of an email sending mechanism.

You can save it to SkyDrive, but then again you have to use a custom API layer (developed by you or by a third-party) to achieve this.

A better choice in my opinion would be having a WCF service that will transmit the byte array of the generated content to a specific location - this will ultimately give you more control over the transmission layer.

Answer (score 1):

You can save images to the MediaLibrary - from where you can access it via the Zune Software and transfer to PC, etc.
This can be done with the [MediaLibrary.SavePicture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.medialibrary.savepicture.aspx) method. (Yes, this is an XNA method but it can be used from within a Silverlight application also.)

The other alternative is to upload it to a webserver and send it from there.

There is currently no way to save songs or movies.

How to upload a file to a webserver very much depends on: the server; the software it is running; and any security concerns realting to the content.
There is the start of a discussion on this at [Uploading XML files from WP7, possible, how to etc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916699/uploading-xml-files-from-wp7-possible-how-to-etc/4917141#4917141)

Comment: How can I upload file to webserver? Is there samples of such thing? And how I will save wav with save picture method?