# WP7 Image Upload

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-7, upload, ftp

I'm trying to create a WP7 application that will upload an image to my website. I tried using FTP but microsoft have removed that feature from WP7. Apparently the only other way at the moment is to call a webservice running on my website that will do the ftp upload for me.

Simple enough, i turn the image into a byte array and make a web request to my website.

But i'm not sure on the code on either side, client or server. I'm using asp but i'm not having much look, i've got as far as turning the image into a byte array but i dont know how i go about sending this data. All the info i've found is for web apps or windows forms not WP7.

Thanks,

James

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hey Cadab have you checked out [this link](http://gregdoesit.com/2009/10/file-upload-in-silverlight-a-simple-solution/) yet? It looks like the code for the application on the client as well as server side. I have not tried this myself but I'm pretty sure it would work.

You should take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622518/very-simple-silverlight-file-upload-example) because it has code and seems pretty close to what your trying to accomplish.

You might also want to check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916699/uploading-xml-files-from-wp7-possible-how-to-etc).

Although these were written in standard silverlight (browser or client) they should work for WP7 with minor modifications.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for that! I'm busy today, will try this out later and let you know, thank you.

Comment: That first link provided everything i needed thanks. Just got to work out why some uploads get corrupted! :)